# How can I pass char values as double values in any matlab function provided I have the double variable of the same name as char(please see detail)?

Tags: matlab

%% I want to pass the values of char (here var_name{1})as that of     double(here x) in histogram function. How can I do that?

```
 % var_name could be much bigger
 h={'h1','h2'}
 var_name ={'x','y'}
 time_step=100;
 for i =1:time_step
   x=%code that extract x from some data file %
   y= %get y from some other file (actually using find command)
  %the time loop will overwrite the x and  y  values 
 ` for k=1:length(var_name)
    %figure  h 

    h{k}=histogram(var_name{k}) % I have been suggested to avoid eval  % 

    %lot of procees to do here for every variable  say  x y than save  the          
     %saveas(h{k},sprintf(...))
   end 

  end
```

Comment: use histogram(x). Get rid of dynamic variables

Comment: hi Sardar Usama. I need to use that for a reason. I know hostogram(x)  would give the direct values, but I need to work with a lot of values  and  that would require different loop (like using different loop for every histogram command)

Comment: If there is such a reason, you need to reconsider your approach.

Comment: suppose I  want to  plot hostgram for 100 different variables (basically array ) and each are result of running time loop. than I need  to  calculate histogram  in a single loop

Comment: Then store 100 such variables in a cell array (not as chars) or struct . There is never any reason to use dynamic variables

Comment: Then store 100 such variables : actually the variable that I am using are  overwritten by a time loop so I need to store them outside of the  time loop

Comment: Apparently you are having [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You had an `X` problem. You thought `Y` would be a solution. Then you got into problem on implementing `Y` but instead of asking about `X`, you asked about `Y`.

Comment: you are right.  but unless I post the whole code  it is not possible to express what problem I am facing.  Can I send  u the code ?

Comment: Please stop asking people for facebook accounts etc. Questions should be solved here, on Stack Overflow, and **asking for personal information can be perceived as a potential scam**. All your comments asking for personal information have been removed, please don't post new ones.

Comment: I will not repeat it , adriaan,  I am a student , just trying to get the problem resolved ,I  thought talking to experts personally would have solved it quicker.  I shall not repeat it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) to evaluate the variable name, giving you the vector of data that variable contains:

```
histogram(eval(var_name{1}));
```

However, I'm guessing there's a better way to approach your problem, since [using dynamically named variables is general not good practice](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval).

Based on your updated example, one non-`eval` way you could do this is using [structures](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) and [dynamic field names](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html):

```
for i = 1:time_step
  data.(var_name{1}) = % code that extract xs from some data file
  data.(var_name{2}) = % get y from some other file (actually using find command)
  for k = 1:length(var_name)
    h{k} = histogram(data.(var_name{k}));
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: The simplest way I can think of is to club all the double  in matrix but that is slower. Is there any other way to do that (to get rid of the bug that may arise due to dynamical variable?)

Comment: Storing data as [multidimensional matrices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html), [cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), or [structures](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) is generally a better way to manage things. Without knowing your specific problem, I can't really give a specific solution.

Comment: % var_name could be much bigger
h={'h1','h2','h3'}
var_name ={'x','y','z'}
time_step=100;
for i =1:time_step
    %the time loop will overwrite the x and  y  values 
    for k=1:length(var_name)
        %figure  h 
        x=%code that extract x from some data file %
        y= %% same here
        h{k}=histpgram(x)
        %lot of procees to do here for every variable  say  x y than save  the figure 
        %saveas(h{k},sprintf(...))
    end 
    
end

Comment: data.(var_name{1})  : do I need to  pass the values in data.(var_name{1})instead of x (provided var_name={'x','y'})

Comment: @VijayKumar: Yes, `data` is a structure with fields `x` and `y` in this case. You can access field `x` by doing `data.x` or `data.('x')` or `data.(var_name{1})`.